# How can I make a JButton activate a compareTo function?

Tags: java, jbutton, listener, compareto, windowbuilder

This is a bit embarrassing. I have a compareTo function that I intend to use on a JButton, so when the user presses it they can see which is the highest ranked object. I already have a Listener class for the JButton but I don't know how to make the Listener use the compareTo function because it needs two parameters.

This is my compareTo function:

```
public int compareTo(Film film1, Film film2) {
    if (film1.getFinalScore() < film2.getFinalScore()) return -1;
    if (film1.getFinalScore() > film2.getFinalScore()) return 1;
    return 0;

}
```

And this is the actionPerformed function in the Listener class:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    this.cm.compareTo(null, null);

}
```

The Auto-correct suggested to put the parameters to null to make it work, but it's obviously never as simple as the Auto-Correct suggests.

So, how can I make the Listener perform the compareTo function using all of my objects to list them from highest to lowest?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you storing the list of Films?

Comment: I'm storing them in a database class.

Comment: You will need to get all the data from the database class and loop through it using the compareTo

Comment: So something along the lines of this?

edit: Sorry meant to put the code in. But something along the lines of for(int i = 0; i< films.size(); i++ )? Where [films] is the database calling the objects?

Comment: Does Ahmed's answer answer your question?

Comment: Yes it does! Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you need to compare 2 Films together you can do that in `Film Class` by implementing `Comparable<Film>` then implementing the `compareTo` method in the class.

After That , Hold your films in any `collection` as `ArrayList` then simply call `Collections.max(films)` to get the max film object in the list.

Here is the a Film class for demonstration:

```
public class Film implements Comparable<Film>{
  int finalScore ;

  public Film(int finalScore){
      this.finalScore = finalScore;
  }

  public int getFinalScore(){
      return this.finalScore;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Film film2) {
      if (this.getFinalScore() < film2.getFinalScore()) return -1;
      if (this.getFinalScore() > film2.getFinalScore()) return 1;
      return 0;
  }
}
```

And this is the main :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Film> films = new ArrayList<>();
        films.add(new Film(100));
        films.add(new Film(400));
        films.add(new Film(200));
        films.add(new Film(300));
        System.out.println(Collections.max(films).getFinalScore());//prints 400     
    }
```

So your actionPerformed will be like this

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Film maxFilm = Collections.max(films);
    //then use maxFilm object to do anything you need

}
```

Comment: Woah, thanks for that detailed reply! I managed to make it work thanks a lot!